# Framework7 Material Icon in android 4.4.2 (KitKat)

Tags: html-framework-7

I was building app that uses new Framework7 Material Icon, It works perfectly find for higher version, but when I try to install the app in kitkat, the UI is distorted and entire app look not usable, higher versions looks perfectly ok. Any workaround or solution available for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug with Android WebView in Android < 4.4 that doesn't support ligatures.

I'm not facing this issue, since i'm using Font Awesome.

For browsers that do not support ligatures, fall back to specifying the icons using numeric character references like the example below:

Go to the official icon font website, lookup the icons you are using and use the code point instead of the ligatures, like `&#xE317;` for keyboard_backspace.

Or even as a last workaround, try to use CrossWalk:

> Crosswalk is a HTML5 runtime, built on open source foundations, which
> extends the web platform with new capabilities. What this means for
> Android developers is, you can now deploy your mobile HTML5
> application with its own runtime without a dependence on the native
> webview that is on your customer's device for all Android 4.0+
> devices.
>
> Uniform runtime across all devices and so you don't have to deal with runtime differences on different devices running different versions of the OS.

Unfortunately CrossWalk does a huge increase on apk size.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think font awesome is better choice for me now to show few icons. let me try

Comment: I'm glad to help.